# Is it still possible to have maps that make a call to mapper.map?

Tags: c#, automapper

With the release of AutoMapper 4.2 the static mapper interface was obsoleted and the new recommended approach is to use DI/IoC to inject the mapper wherever needed.

I am working on upgrading my project to this version and I have moved my configurations into an implementation of the `Profile` class. The problem I'm having is that a couple of my maps are reliant on being able to make additional `Map` calls.

Here are the maps in question:

```
CreateMap<ProjectEntity, FavoritesNode>()
    .ConstructUsing((ProjectEntity src) => Mapper.Map<FavoritesGroupModel>(src))
    .IgnoreMember(dest => dest.DisplayValue);

CreateMap<ProjectEntity, FavoritesGroupModel>()
    .MapMember(dest => dest.DisplayValue, src => src.ProjectName)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Items, src => src.Tasks);

CreateMap<ProjectTaskEntity, FavoritesNode>()
    .ConstructUsing((ProjectTaskEntity src) => Mapper.Map<FavoritesComboItemModel>(src))
    .IgnoreMember(dest => dest.DisplayValue);

CreateMap<ProjectTaskEntity, FavoritesComboItemModel>()
    .MapMember(dest => dest.DisplayValue, src => src.ProjectTaskName)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Key, src => src.Id)
    .IgnoreMember(dest => dest.IsFavorite);
```

To add some context, both `FavoritesComboItemModel` and `FavoritesGroupModel` inherit from `FavoritesNode` and a `ProjectEntity` has a list of `ProjectTaskEntity`. These maps are used to adapt the rather simple Project structure into the completely dynamic tree structure that the Favorites Models are use for.

So given this configuration is there any way that I can still make these map calls within the new instance api?

*`IgnoreMember` and `MapMember` are my own shortcut extensions to the corresponding ForMember variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a direct answer to the question, the same goal can be achieved with the `As<T>` method on `IMappingExpression`

Here is the sample from the question with this implemented:

```
CreateMap<ProjectEntity, FavoritesNode>()
    .As<FavoritesGroupModel>();

CreateMap<ProjectEntity, FavoritesGroupModel>()
    .MapMember(dest => dest.DisplayValue, src => src.ProjectName)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Items, src => src.Tasks);

CreateMap<ProjectTaskEntity, FavoritesNode>()
    .As<FavoritesComboItemModel>();

CreateMap<ProjectTaskEntity, FavoritesComboItemModel>()
    .MapMember(dest => dest.DisplayValue, src => src.ProjectTaskName)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Key, src => src.Id)
    .IgnoreMember(dest => dest.IsFavorite);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's rather easy.

For the ConstructUsing method, you have an overload that recieves a Func with a ResolutionContext parameter. The resolution context has an Engine property, that holds a reference to the mapping engine that's currently doing the mapping.

It would look something like this:

```
CreateMap<ProjectTaskEntity, FavoritesNode>()
    .ConstructUsing( ctx => ctx.Engine.Map<FavoritesComboItemModel>(ctx.SourceValue))
    .IgnoreMember(dest => dest.DisplayValue);
```

There's also a ResolveUsing overload that receives a mapping context.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for adding an answer that covers the direct question being asked.